# How to create user specific content, that is invisible to others?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication

I am absolutely new to Ruby on Rails, even to programming at all. I got started with Michael Hartl's [Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) using Rails 3.0.10. Now I alter its aim towards creating an application that allows users to manage their own "projects". These projects are to be exclusively available to the logged-in user, thus, invisible to others.

My problem is: I am unable to create a page with an URL like "~/users/1/projects", I don't know about the routing. All i get done is "~/projects", which is fairly not what i want at all. So, how do I get this problem fixed? Or am I totally off track with that idea?

I generated a Projects model by scaffolding. So, how can I implement it for the signed-in users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this would be done by creating a nested resource. when you are new to rails and programming you should work yourself a way through a lot of tutorials and guides.

a good place to get an overview are the official rails guides. in this specific case the chapter about routing: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :users do
  resources :projects
end
```

Comment: Thank you phoet, now I - at least - know what to search for.

Comment: if this answers your question, you should mark it as resolved. if you liked it, vote the answer up. this is how you thank the people instead of writing comments.

Comment: This gave me an initial start with a rat tail of more unanswered questions - but sure, that helped.